# Removing/locking a dropdown list using range.validation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lock an existing dropdown list. I have set the value of the list to "2" and I don't want the user to be able to change it. I tried a various things and this is what I have right now but it doesn't seem to work

```
 Range("J16") = 2
            With Range("J16").Validation
                .Delete x1ValidateList
                .InCellDropdown = False
            End With
```

I get a compile error at .Delete ...

second question, 
I am also trying to set the value of a cell and I don't want the user to be able to edit it:

```
Range("J17").Select 
Selection.Locked = True
```

this doesn't seem to do the trick either! I understand that locking only works if i protect the sheet but I don't want to protect the sheet because user needs to be able to add other parts in the sheet.

Please help, I am pretty new to the VBA world :)

Comment: Locking only works if the sheet is protected. Re the first bit what exactly does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What happens?

Comment: `Range("J17").Locked = True` just means that if you do a `Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect` that the `J17` then is locked. Note that by default **all** cells are `.Locked = True` so actually you need to unlock the cells you want to be editable after `.Protect`.

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: What happens if the user accidentally selects the wrong thing and needs to change it?

Comment: There are no alternatives you need to use the [Range.Locked property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked) and the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) in combination. See the linked documentation for how they work.

Comment: Note that `x1ValidateList` must be `xlValidateList` there is no `1` (one) in it but a lower case `L`!

Comment: Good catch! But still getting a compile error

Comment: @tigeravatar user can't select anything, i want to lock in an answer based on something else the user selects one step before getting to this sheet

Comment: @actuarial.codes you really should read the documentations of the methods you use. According to [Validation.Delete method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.delete) this method has no parameters.

Comment: @actuarial.codes That makes no sense. If the user cannot select anything at all then you don't need a drop down or validation.

Comment: If it's just a cell you want to lock, you really don't need to go to these lengths. In `SelectionChange` method of the sheet, use `Intersect` to identify the range. If it is the range you don't want user to change, just throw them out and display a msg along the lines of: **This is a reserved cell and cannot be changed**

Comment: @Zac Worth to mention that `.Protect` is quite secure while this method can be easily tricked. Anyway I think real security is not needed here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: completely agreed but like you mentioned, I don't think OP is after "real security". It seems a lot of hassle for what OP is trying to achieve. I don't normally recommend this method but I think it meets the need in this situation

Comment: well i want to be able to lock the two cells so users can't edit it period, it has to be secure (with no way around it)

Comment: @actuarial.codes Then `.Lock` and `.Protect` the sheet as I said is the only option you have. `Protect` is the only secure way to protect a sheet with password and disable editing of specific ranges.